# Best ways to sort array of arrays?

Tags: arrays, sorting, raku, indices

I need to sort an array of arrays; the `.sort` method seems to work by
default. But what is a good way to sort by different indices of the
inner arrays?

The array to be sorted is outer larger array: (birthday in 'mmddyy' format)

```
my @allRecords = [ [birthday1 firstName1 lastName1 [data1]
                   [birthday2 firstName2 lastName2 [data2] 
                   ...
                   [birthdayN firstNameN lastNameN [dataN] ];

@allRecords.sort by itself sorts by birthdays.
```

What is a better way to sort by firstName or lastName or by data inside the inner arrays?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `sort` method [takes a sub as optional argument](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/sort#(List)_routine_sort). If its arity is 1, it uses the return value as comparison operands; if its arity is 2, you can manually do the comparison between  elements however you see fit by returning one of `Less`, `Same` or `More`.

Given your example, we can sort by first name like this:

```
@allRecords.sort(*.[1]);
```

We can sort by last name, then first name, then birthday by doing the separate comparisons explicitly like this:

```
@allRecords.sort(-> $a, $b {
    $a[2] cmp $b[2] || $a[1] cmp $b[1] || $a[0] cmp $b[0]
});
```

or again implicitly by transforming the operands:

```
@allRecords.sort(*.[2...0]);
```

Transforming the birthday entry so we sort by year first is left as an exercise for the reader, but one way to do it would be to add something like

```
.comb(2).list.rotate(-1).join
```

where appropriate.

Comment: You can sort by last name, then first name, then birthday like this: `@a.sort: *[2...0]`

Comment: 2 more questions: (1) what is the difference between *.[1] vs *[1]; whatever star represents an inner array; should I use *[] instead of *.[] with the extra dot between * and []? (2) range operator .. or stub operator for a slice of the inner array? Thank you very much ! I am avidly learning perl6.

Comment: @lisprogtor: re (1), there should not be any difference - I just find the former more readable; re (2), while range objects often behave like lists of integers, conceptually, they are a bit different (they are closer to mathematical intervals); in particular, you cannot count downwards using a range, and have to use the *sequence operator* `...` instead

Comment: I see ! Thank you again Christoph ! To exit type 'exit' or '^D'
> my $x = 1..5
1..5
> say $x
1..5
> say $x.list
(1 2 3 4 5)
> my $y = 5..1
5..1
> say $y.list
()
> my $z=5...1
(5 4 3 2 1)
>